# Amoebas and computation

Tags: reference-request, cellular-automata

Today I found out about amoeba based computing and optic computing in a  popular math book  *In Pursuit of the Traveling Salesman: Mathematics at the Limits of Computation* by William J. Cook. Searching more online In [Amoeba-Based Emergent Computing:Combinatorial Optimization and Autonomous
Meta-Problem Solving](http://cis.csuohio.edu/~munakata/publs/pdf/IJUC10.pdf) the authors conclude:

> When applied to some techniques in automated reasoning and machine
>   learning [34],meta-problem solving may be a useful concept to create
>   autonomous agents that are capable of coping with unexpected
>   situations. Suppose that our computing system is developed to be
>   embedded in a control system of an autonomous agent such as a mobile
>   robot. The standard problem-solving process to find a solution to a
>   given problem  would correspond to the agent’s computing process to
>   select an appropriate behavior in an expected situation by following
>   instructions of a given program prescribed in advance by a programmer.
>   However, the program prescribed only for expected situations would
>   always be insufficient for the agent to act in an actual environment
>   where unexpected situations arise very often. The agent may
>   unexpectedly be stuck in a stalemated situation in which the given
>   program is helpless for finding a way out of the stalemate. In such a
>   case, if a meta-problem solver was incorporated in the agent’s control
>   system, the agent evolves the program and may succeed in finding an
>   emergent solution to overcome the stalemate owing to the meta-problem
>   solver’s capability of the spontaneous destabilization. This is a
>   desirable scenario that we picture in our minds as a potential
>   application of meta-problem solving.

But the resources (there is not even a Wikipedia page) on this is sparse.

1. Is there a formal treatment of amoeba-based computing (abc) that attempts 
   to prove some metamathematical theorems other than TSP?
2. How is cellular automata (CA) used to model amoeba?

Some Useful Links:

- http://cis.csuohio.edu/~munakata/publs/pdf/IPMU08.pdf
- http://cis.csuohio.edu/~munakata/publs/pdf/IJUC10.pdf
- http://academia.edu/984681/Problem-size_scalability_of_amoeba-based_neurocomputer_for_traveling_salesman_problem
- http://academia.edu/595255/Amoeba-based_chaotic_neurocomputing_Combinatorial_optimization_by_coupled_biological_oscillators
- http://academia.edu/3346238/Amoeba-based_computing_for_traveling_salesman_problem_Long-term_correlations_between_spatially_separated_individual_cells_of_Physarum_polycephalum
- http://iopscience.iop.org/1748-3190/7/3/036013
- http://www.news-gazette.com/opinion/editorials/2007-07-23/ui-professor-seeks-harness-strength-amoeba-computer-cores.html
- http://passat.crhc.illinois.edu/rakeshk/iccad12_cam.pdfhttp://passat.crhc.illinois.edu/rakeshk/iccad12_cam.pdf

Comment: There are also numerous papers by Adamatzky on [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/find/all/1/all:+AND+physarum+polycephalum/0/1/0/all/0/1)